# Why do i need Hibernate Validator to run a Custom Spring Validator?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a custom spring validator to validates a role DTO class but when I called it using @Valid annotation or by any other means (like data binder validation or calling validate method) nothing happens. I didn't understand if i'm doing something wrong, i have spring validation starter as dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But when i added the Hibernate Validator it started to validate normally but why? wasn't supposed to spring-boot-starter-validation solve that as it related to spring ?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

DTO

```
@Getter @Setter
public class UserRegistrationDTO {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
    private String email;
}
```

Validator

```
@Component(value = "userRegistrationValidator")
public class UserRegistrationValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return UserRegistrationDTO.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO = (UserRegistrationDTO) target;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors,"password", "password.empty", "The password must not be empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors,"confirmPassword", "cpassword.empty", "You have to confirm you password");

        if (userRegistrationDTO.getPassword() != null) {
            if (userRegistrationDTO.getPassword().length() < 5 || userRegistrationDTO.getPassword().length() > 25)
                errors.rejectValue("password", "password.size", "The password size must be between 5 to 25");

            if (userRegistrationDTO.getConfirmPassword() != null && !userRegistrationDTO.getPassword().equals(userRegistrationDTO.getConfirmPassword()))
                errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "password.not_equals", "The password is not equals");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class RegisterController {

    @Qualifier("userRegistrationValidator")
    private final Validator validator;

    @PostMapping
    public String registerProcessing(@ModelAttribute("userRegistration") @RequestBody UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, userRegistrationDTO, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "login/signup";
        }

        // ... 

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

My first attempt was setting the validator directly to the data binder. Therefore, i would not need to call the validator. Nothing happens.

```
@Qualifier("userRegistrationValidator")
private final Validator validator;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    webDataBinder.addValidators(validator);
}
```

My second attempt was call the validate method but it still doesn't work.

```
@PostMapping
    public String registerProcessing(@ModelAttribute("userRegistration") @RequestBody UserRegistrationDTO userRegistrationDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        validator.validate(userRegistrationDTO, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "login/signup";
        }
    // ...
}
```